# Overriding a var in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, overriding

I'm trying to learn Swift by following different tutorials, but I have come into a problem. I have the following code:

```
Class Vehicle {
    var seats = 5
    var maxSpeed = 100
}

class Bike : Vehicle{
    override var seats = 3
}
```

But I keep getting an error regarding trying to override `var seats`, stating `Cannot override with a stored property 'seats'`.

What am I doing wrong? I thought I could override inherited variables?

Answer (score 4):

You don't actually need to override the property, just initialize with a different value, which can be done in the initializer:

```
class Vehicle {
    var seats = 5
    var maxSpeed = 100
}

class Bike : Vehicle{
    override init() {
        super.init()
        self.seats = 3
    }
}
```

As for overriding properties, the [lang reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Inheritance.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH17-ID196) states that:

> You can override an inherited instance or class property to provide your own custom getter and setter for that property, or to add property observers to enable the overriding property to observe when the underlying property value changes.

Comment: Hmmmm I'm aware that I can initialise with a different value but in the swift documentation ([link] https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Inheritance.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH17-ID193) one class defined a variable var currentSpeed = 0.0 but in a subclass later on (sub class automaticCar : Car) var currentSpeed was over ridden with override var currentSpeed: Double {..... how come this is allowed and mine isn't?

Comment: In that case you are providing a custom getter - you can't override a stored property with another stored property just to set a different initial value.

Comment: Ohh ok so if I wanted to override my seats variable from my super class I have to define a custom getter for that variable in my subclass?

Comment: Correct - you are actually turning it into a computed property